# how do i use images from the www in bing maps (win8)

Tags: javascript, windows-8, bing-maps

my aim is to create a bing map with some pushpins in it.

so i have the following function:

```
function addPushPin(pos, merchantId) {
    var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin({ latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude }, {
        icon: 'http://.../'+merchantId+'.png'
    });
    map.entities.push(pin);
}
```

but, bing maps don't seem to be able to load images from the www. (i tryed it with local images and this worked)

the icon url is a good one. if i copy paste it to a browser i can see the image, but i can't display it in my bing map.

any idea why? and what i can do that it `works`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work just fine with a URL.

To test with a URL, go to the Bing Maps portal URL ( Pushpin example )

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Pushpins2

On the page you will see an example at the bottom. Replace the icon url with your own http URL, click on the Run button and you will see that your Pushpin will get loaded from your url.

Example

```
map.entities.clear(); 
var pushpinOptions = {icon: 'http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/wp-content/uploads/mapicons/shape-default/color-3875d7/shapecolor-white/shadow-1/border-color/symbolstyle-color/symbolshadowstyle-no/gradient-no/exchequer.png', width: 30, height: 50}; 
var pushpin= new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), pushpinOptions);
map.entities.push(pushpin);
```

Comment: i just forgot to set height and width. i thought it will automatically set it.